# Cannot set desired time to my Gregorian calendar

Tags: java, android, datetime, calendar

The problem in the below code is that I am trying to set EVENING time to 6 P.M. please ignore the Calendar.evening values as it was for testing purpose. 
here is my LOG file

> D/Notification: MORN Tue Nov 14 16:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017 vs EVE Tue Nov 14 16:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017
>
> > MORN: Tue Nov 14 16:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017 vs Tue Nov 14 16:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017
> >     EVE: Tue Nov 14 16:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017 vs Tue Nov 14 16:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017

now the problem here is that both of the getTime() are returning CURRENT TIME.

### I want the IF LOOP to execute at a 4 pm and 8 am, for this instance, my logic seems pretty legit! Please point me to the error

```
public class MyNotificationService extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


static Calendar eve,morn;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    morn=Calendar.getInstance();
    morn.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
    morn.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    morn.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    morn.set(Calendar.AM_PM,1);

    eve=Calendar.getInstance();
    eve.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
    eve.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    eve.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    eve.set(Calendar.AM_PM,1);

    Log.d("Notification", "MORN "+morn.getTime().toString() +" vs EVE "+eve.getTime().toString());

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    setTimer();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}



void setTimer(){

    Timer timer = new Timer ();
    TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {

        @Override
        public void run () {
            Calendar now=Calendar.getInstance();
            now.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
            now.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);


            Log.d("Notification MORN", morn.getTime().toString() +" vs "+now.getTime().toString());
            if (now.compareTo(morn)==0||now.getTime().equals(morn.getTime())) {
                Log.d("Notification Func", eve.getTime().toString() + " MORNING exe");
                Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (isInternetOn(getApplicationContext())){
                            getCaseDetails();
                        }else {
                            setNotification("Internet not available","Please check your Cases");
                        }
                    }
                };
                mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
            }
            Log.d("Notification EVE", eve.getTime().toString() +" vs "+now.getTime().toString());
            if (now.compareTo(eve)==0||now.getTime().equals(eve.getTime())) {
                    Log.d("Notification Func", eve.getTime().toString() + " EVENING exe");
                Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getCaseDetails();
                    }
                };
                mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
            }
        }
    };
//        timer.schedule (hourlyTask, 0L, 1000*60*60);
    timer.schedule (hourlyTask, 0L, 30*1000);
}


void getDetails() {
   }



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Notification Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}



public void setNotification(String titleStr,String descStr) {

   setting alarm here.
}

}
```

Comment: Try using HOUR instead of HOUR_OF_DAY. Reading [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR) it indicates that HOUR is the hour in the morning/afternoon, while is relative to midnight, ignoring AM/PM.

Comment: I have taken care of AM/PM by setting the value carefully, AM=0 / PM=1

Comment: That careful adjustment makes the calendar completely ignore your HOUR_OF_DAY setting, you need to set HOUR.

Comment: it fixed the problem thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AM/PM requires the use of `Calendar.HOUR`, not `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`, which is ignored when setting AM/PM:

```
Calendar morn = Calendar.getInstance();
morn.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
morn.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
morn.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
morn.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

System.out.println(someDateFormat.format(morn.getTime()));
// current hour

morn = Calendar.getInstance();
morn.set(Calendar.HOUR, 4);
morn.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
morn.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
morn.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

System.out.println(someDateFormat.format(morn.getTime()));
// correct hour
```